# Json_encode changing the order of my query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-order-by, json

I have a mysql query that orders by a column.  It works fine if I just run the php.  After I use json_encode and send it to the client, the order is changed to the primary key.  Why does it do this and is there a solution?

Query looks like:

```
try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Batik', 'root', 'root');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $_SESSION['table'] = $_SESSION['category'] = $table = $_GET['button'];
    $count = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY `order` ASC");
    $count->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $myarray = array();
    while ($row = $count->fetch()) {
        $id = array_shift($row);
        $myarray[$id] = $row;
    }
    print json_encode($myarray);
}  catch (PDOException $exception) {
    echo "There was an error uploading your information, please contact James for assistance. "; 
    error_log($exception->getMessage());
 };
```

So, the output I want and get in plain php is like this:   (ID = primary_key)

```
  Order:     ID:      Location:
  1             4         foto1.jpg
  2             5         foto3.jpg
  3             3         foto2.jpg
  4             2          foto4.jpg
  5             1          foto5.jpg
```

After I json_encode the array and output to client, I get this:    (ID = primary_key)

```
  Order:     ID:       Location:
  5             1          foto5.jpg
  4             2          foto4.jpg
  3             3          foto2.jpg
  1             4          foto1.jpg
  2             5          foto3.jpg
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What exactly is changed where, can you clarify and perhaps show an example? At which point is the data changed?

Comment: I've had this issue before too, in my case I ended up having to reorder it in Javascript by passing an `order` array alonside my original data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is : don't use

```
$id = array_shift($row);
$myarray[$id] = $row;
```

to build your array. Build a real 0-based numerically indexed array instead with this syntax :

```
$myarray[] = $row;
```

and the array will be built with the items in the order they are looped over, although with a slightly different record structure (no meaningful keys).

As an alternative, to preserve your current structure, you could order the array in php instead of SQL with the *sort family of functions (**usort** in particular), like so (assuming your "order" field is numeric, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php for an example with a string-type field) :

```
while ($row = $count->fetch()) {
    $myarray[] = $row;
}
usort($myarray,function ($a, $b){return ($a > $b) ? 1 : -1;});
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was simple.

Answer (score 4):

the client orders the array atuomatically if you use a literal object with numbers.
So if you leave out the id you shuould get the right content.

replace

```
while ($row = $count->fetch()) {
    $id = array_shift($row);
    $myarray[$id] = $row;
}

//doing so you create this
json array=[
 0=undefined,
 1={order:5,id:1;location1},
 2={order:4,id:2;location2},
 3={order:3,id:3;location3},
 4={order:2,id:4;location4},
]
//error
```

with

```
while ($row = $count->fetch()) {
    $myarray[] = $row;
}
```

basicaly you transform your literal object into a simple array.wich can lead to several errors if you start to delete some images.

then you probably just need the id and the location

so

```
SELECT id,location FROM ... ORDER BY order ASC
```

and you have

```
[[1,location1],[2,location2]]
```

or

```
[{id:1,location:"location1"},{id:2,location:"location2"}]
  //0 wich is order 1        //1 wich is order 2
```

**The sort order created by your mysql query is the json array index.**