# php mysql order by not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql

Given the following query that returns the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY article_date DESC
```

but in PHP the results are still ordered ASC.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
require_once('connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT article_name, article_text, article_date FROM articles ORDER BY article_date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result_array = array();
$rows = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

http_response_code(200);
$result_array['status'] = 200;
$result_array['error'] = "";
$result_array['result'] = $rows;

exit(json_encode($result_array));
?>
```

I've tried different approaches like `DATE_FORMAT` or changing the type of the field to `timestamp` type.

My articles table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `article_text` text NOT NULL,
  `article_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Your observations are not consistent with the query you showed us.  Are you sure this is the query and code which actually resulted in an ascending order result set?

Comment: the problem is on `json_encode` see the answer here: [Json_encode changing the order of my query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693404/json-encode-changing-the-order-of-my-query)

Comment: Interesting, thank you @Atmahadli I will dig about this more.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would assume that your ID would be auto-increment, meaning that it would be in chronological order by the ID because after every post, a the ID would increase by one. So what I would suggest is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

If that doesn't work, tell me and I will help you out.

Comment: You now assume articles are entered in order of the date. But I could very well today write stories about all last week's races, not doing in order

Comment: @IvoP In his SQL code, you can see that he is inserting the current timestamp into his table, meaning it would be inputted by order of date and ID would work.